# Does nullity at one point implies nullity everywhere?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, derivatives

Consider the following definition of the derivation.
[image]

Now, consider a derivation $\delta_{p} :C^{r}(R^{n})\rightarrow R$ , i.e. it is defined on r-times differentiable functions defined on the manifold $R^{n}$. This derivation satisfies the Leibnitz's law: 
$$\delta(fg)=f\delta(g)+g\delta(f).$$
Denote $m_{r}=\left \{ f\in C^{r}(R^{n}):f(0)=0 \right \}$ and let $m^{2}_{r}$ be a subspace spanned by the functions of the form $fg$ for $f,g\in m_{r}$. I am stuck at proving that $\delta$ is zero on all elements of $m^{2}_{r}$.

Since for every function $h$ in $m^{2}_{r}$ it is true that at the point $p=0$ $(\delta h)(0)=0$, I believe that on other points $p \neq 0$ it will be zero as well. But I don't see a way how to prove this. Any suggestions would be of great value.

UPDATE: The whole story related to my question is from Lee "Manifolds and differential geometry"
[image]

Comment: It is not because a function vanishes at $0$ that it must vanish everywhere! Why do you expect this to be true? Just take $n=1$ and $r = 1$ for instance, it is not because $f=g=x$ means $fg = x^2 \in m_r^2$, that $\delta(fg) = 2x$ is identically zero. Did I understand the question well?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Yes, now that you simply pointed out why the statement is not true, I am wondering, what have I misunderstood in the original excercise. Because it seems that the question asks to prove that derivation is identically zero on all $m^{2}_{r}$

Comment: You should be careful with your definition of a derivation. As you wrote it in the first line of your question, a derivation is something that takes in a function $f$ and returns a real number. However, in that case your statement of the Leibniz rule does not make sense, because $f\delta(g)+g\delta(f)$ is not a number but a function.

Comment: @GCD Thanks for the comment. I should have really made clear that the derivation is always evaluated at the point. I corrected it.

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem then. The derivation comes with a specific point $p$, which Lee takes WLOG to be $0$. If the derivation is evaluated at the point, then it is trivial that $\delta h = 0$ whenever $h\in m_r^2$, exactly by the Leibniz rule. Your paragraph which begins "Since for every function.." is missing the point: there is no such thing as $\delta h (0)$; $\delta h$ is a number, not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps if the derivation is defined as $\delta(f) = f'(0)$ (which is a map from $C^1(\mathbb R)$ to $\mathbb R$ and satisfies Leibniz's rule), then $\delta(h) = 0$ for $h \in m_r^2$. Otherwise we cannot say much.

Hope that helps,